# Passwords not showing in Google Chrome but are suggested at login and visible on passwords.google.com

Tags: google-chrome

I've been experiencing an issue with Google Chrome (Version 116.0.5845.96) where my saved passwords are not displaying within the application itself. Strangely, when I visit a login page, Chrome still suggests the appropriate saved passwords for autofill, and I can also see them listed on the website https://passwords.google.com. However, the passwords are not visible in the actual Google Chrome settings.

Is anyone else encountering this problem or aware of a solution? I've tried restarting the browser, signing in and out of my Google account, and checking for updates, but the passwords remain missing from the Chrome settings. Any insights into resolving this discrepancy between the suggested passwords and their absence in the Chrome application would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!